# how to write Current Raw Access Logs file at server side

Tags: php

I am to write current raw access file at server but I am unable to reach to that file path I am using the following code

```
    const GENERAL_ERROR_DIR = '/logs/agent_log'; 

    public function general($msg) 
    { 
        $date = date('d/m/Y h:i:s'); 
        $log = $msg . "   |  Date:  " . $date . "\t"; 
        error_log($log,3, self::GENERAL_ERROR_DIR); 
    }
```

In above code I am unable to reach at the destination to that file.how to i do this.

Comment: Check permissions on the path for the account that the webserver runs under.

Answer (score 1):

You need to write to the actual server side path, which will be something like `/home/yourdomain.com/htdocs/logs/agent_log` you can get the path of your current script with `getcwd();` so to write to the same path as the script itself try:

```
const GENERAL_ERROR_DIR = getcwd();

public function general($msg) 
 { 
    $date = date('d/m/Y h:i:s'); 
    $log = $msg."   |  Date:  ".$date."\t"; 
    error_log($log,3, self::GENERAL_ERROR_DIR); 
 }
```

You can then edit it to be the correct path to your folder. Something like `const GENERAL_ERROR_DIR = getcwd() . '/../../logs/agent_log`;

Also as @ethrbunny mentioned check the permission for any of the folders you are writing to these should be set so they can be written to.

Answer (score 1):

Be sure file exists and apache/httpd have the proper file read/write permission.
generally giving the write permission for the group will work. 
This [File permission](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/FilePermissions) could help.

In short try this if you already in Linux environment:

`chmod 666 /logs/agent_log`
**OR**
`sudo chmod 666 /logs/agent_log`

This will give the read+write permission for all.